# Ceramic heating bulb for pets as fermentation chamber heater

Tags: fermentation-temperature, temperature-control, sour

Looking for people who have experience with [ceramic heating bulbs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MXUT5RH) - I know these are effective for maintaining primary fermentation temps but I am curious about higher temps.

Can you use (or do you have experience using) one of these ceramic heaters to increase temps to as high as 100 degrees fahrenheit (for souring) in a large vessel (chest freezer)?

Comment: I suspect this is going depend a lot on your conditions (good insulation, not too cold a room. what kind of container, wattage of bulb.  I suspect you will need to experiment to know for sure

Comment: might go with one of these https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003XDTWN2/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK one of those puts out a lot of heat.  You could also consider a Fermwrap heater, which goes on sale once or twice a year for $10 or so.